# Unable to change content within html object from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

Working on a solution for a client where they want to have three websites within one browser window, to interact with them without having to have multiple windows displayed. Originally I thought iframes would work, but the software used disables that functionality somehow, so after doing some research, I found that objects might do a similar function.

One issue that I'm having is that I want to be able to have sub windows have their content changed based upon actions in another object. For example if I have a link in object three to load a link into object two, I could. However I'm not having much luck in having them communicate between each other. Does anyone know of a way this can be achieved, if it can at all?

The current code that I'm working with to perform this action.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AAA</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function doPage(targetObjectPane) {
            var objTag = document.getElementById(targetObjectPane);
            if (objTag != null) {
                objTag.setAttribute('data', 'http://www.toronto.ca/');
                alert('Page should have been changed');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div style="float:left;width:65%;height:100%;">
        <object name="frameone" id="frameone" data="http://www.tsn.ca/" standby="loading data" title="loading" width="100%" height="100%" type="text/html">
            Alternative Content
        </object>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width:35%;height:100%;">
        <object name="frametwo" id="frametwo" data="http://www.cbc.ca/" standby="loading data" title="loading" width="100%" height="50%" type="text/html">
            Alternative Content
        </object>
        <object name="framethree" id="framethree" data="test.html" standby="loading data" title="loading" width="100%" height="50%" type="text/html">
            Alternative Content
        </object>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And within object frameThree,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="doPage(frametwo);">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In a nutshell, the javascript attempt to manipulate object content has ran into undefined errors, as I assume being seperate sites, none of them can see each other as children of the same browser window. The current execution of doPage shows the function is undefined. If that function code is moved to test.html, then the referenced object name frameTwo is not found.

Comment: _"Originally I thought iframes would work, but the software used disables that functionality somehow"_ - What is "the software used" here? For your initial description of what you're trying to do I would've gone with iframes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [same-origin protections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) in a browser, you cannot manipulate content across different domains.  So from one domain, you cannot reach into another site's contents (in a frame or iframe) if that other site has a different domain.

---

Looking at your code, I think you probably want this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doPage(frametwo);">Test</a>
```

to be this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doPage('frametwo');">Test</a>
```

because `"frametwo"` needs to be passed to `doPage('frameTwo')` as a string.

When I try your code, I find that the `<object>` does not change the HTML it is displaying when the data attribute is changed.  I don't know if that's by design or not.  But, if you create a new `<object>` with the new data reference and insert it to replace the prior one, it does work like this:

```
function doPage2(targetObjectPane) {
    var objTag = document.getElementById(targetObjectPane);
    if (objTag) {
        // create new object tag with new data reference
        var newObj = document.createElement("object");
        newObj.width = "100%";
        newObj.height = "50%";
        newObj.data = "http://www.toronto.ca/";
        newObj.type = "text/html";
        newObj.id = "frametwo";
        newObj.name = "frametwo";
        // insert new object tag
        objTag.parentNode.insertBefore(newObj, objTag);        
        // remove old object tag
        objTag.parentNode.removeChild(objTag);
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/K7r32/

Comment: "When I try your code, I find that the <object> does not change the HTML it is displaying when the data attribute is changed. I don't know if that's by design or not. " Yes I wanted to have it where if I clicked on one link in one object, it would change the html contents in another object. From how it's sounding that's not doable.

Comment: @canadiancreed - based on the behavior seen in browsers, that appears to be correct.  The work-around it to use this function to replace the object tag with an identical one that has a new data attribute.